# splitting multiple return statements into different functions

Tags: python, recursion

I'm implementing a backtracking solution and have multiple return statements. I don't see a way to split this into multiple functions, so there is only one return statement per function. The code is..

```
  def solve_grid(self, grid, row=0, col=0):


    row, col = self.find_next(grid, row, col)
    if row == -1:
        return True
    for num in range(1,10):
        if self.isValid(grid, row, col, num):
            grid[row][col] = num
            if self.solve_grid(grid, row, col):
                return True
            grid[row][col] = 0
    return False
```

I;ve tried splitting it up as follows

```
def check(self, grid, row, col):
    boolean = None
    row, col = self.find_next(grid, row, col)
    if row == -1:
        boolean = True
    return boolean

def solve_grid(self, grid, row=0, col=0):

    boolean = None
    if not self.check(grid, row, col):
        for num in range(1,10):
            if self.isValid(grid, row, col, num):
                grid[row][col] = num
                if self.solve_grid(grid, row, col):
                    boolean = True
                else: 
                    boolean = False
            grid[row][col] = 0
    return boolean
```

This results in a maximum recursion depth. I'm a bit lost a to how to go about this, I've never really had to try to split multiple return statements before. Any pointers or tips would be helpful.

Comment: I'm not certain having multiple return statements in a single function is a bad thing in the general case.  Were you getting a stack overflow error in your original code as well?

Comment: You're hitting the maximum recursion depth because every time the `isValid()` call succeeds, you call `solve_grid()` again.

Comment: Well, if `isValid()` fails at reasonable depths that will serve as a base case. I am not certain that is intrinsically wrong.

Comment: I was not just depth error, and yes I realize this it's checking the sudoku grid and trying to solve it by backtracking the original works but when trying to split the return statements up this happens. So how would I go about rearranging this? The multiple return statements we're preventing this and handling the cases. As for multiple return statements trying to split it up for readibility, never been a fan of multiple returns

Comment: Does any other code (such as `isValid`) call `solve_grid`?

Comment: It does not, if it would be helpful I could post that block as well. isValid has multiple return statements as well. It simply checks the rows and columns of the grid for conflicts with the current number attempting to be input. I'm trying to split up this funciton first, so don't know if that could possibly be where the error lies.

Comment: Updated `i` is `row`, forgot to change it switched from i,j to row, col

Comment: The only difference I can see is your different indentation (and thus semantics) for `grid[row][col] = 0`. Is that intentional?

Comment: It was the third line in the first block i changed and the corresponding line in the second, and yes that was intentional had an indentation error. The way it was originally would have never reset the number in that cell. The solution posted works also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want to do is remove the multiple returns, this will do it

```
def solve_grid(self, grid, row=0, col=0):
    row, col = self.find_next(grid, row, col)
    if row == -1:
        result = True
    else:
        result = False
        for num in range(1,10):
            if self.isValid(grid, row, col, num):
                grid[row][col] = num

                if self.solve_grid(grid, row, col):
                    result=True
                    break

                grid[row][col] = 0

    return result
```

You could also convert the `for` loop into a `while` to remove the `break`

```
def solve_grid(self, grid, row=0, col=0):
    row, col = self.find_next(grid, row, col)
    if row == -1:
        result = True
    else:
        result = False
        num = 0
        while num < 9 and not result:
            num += 1
            if self.isValid(grid, row, col, num):
                grid[row][col] = num

                if self.solve_grid(grid, row, col):
                    result=True
                else:
                    grid[row][col] = 0

    return result
```

But I personally find your original form to be more readable.

One final simplification gets rid of a level of indentation by initializing `result` with the check of `row`

```
def solve_grid(self, grid, row=0, col=0):
    row, col = self.find_next(grid, row, col)
    result = (row == -1)
    num = 0
    while num < 9 and not result:
        num += 1
        if self.isValid(grid, row, col, num):
            grid[row][col] = num

            if self.solve_grid(grid, row, col):
                result=True
            else:
                grid[row][col] = 0


    return result
```

And now, I think it's fairly clean

Comment: Was this an issue of a boolean being `None` versus `False` or `True`?